# Yosemite - remapping Russian layout

Tags: keyboard, macos

Is there a way to remap keys in foreign layout by modifying existing layout or creating your own?

Yosemite (as well as Mavericks before that) has "Russian-PC" and "Russian" layout, both missing "ё" letter. PC layout normally would map it to '`' key, to the left from 1.

Comment: @tetsujin No, Russian layouts do not have option dead keys for adding diacritics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom Russian PC layout you can download which has the ë where you expect it, even though you are using an ANSI keyboard instead of an ISO one.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46870715/k/RussianPC2.keylayout

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I wonder why this is not default or an option for Russian.

Comment: @AlexeiDanchenkov  I suspect it is not included because such a layout will not work right on the ISO type keyboard which is normally used in Europe and Russia, and people with ANSI keyboards are provided with two layouts, Russian and Russian Qwerty, which have the ё on them.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simple enough to find it from the Keyboard Viewer.. System Prefs > Keyboard

If I swap my UK keyboard to Russian, I get the ë at the very right of the centre row of letters, mapped onto what is normally backslash & pipe \ & |

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If the user has an ANSI keyboard, instead of the ISO shown here, the ë will be one row further up on the Russian layout, and will disappear on the Russian -PC layout, being replaced by ].

Comment: Opening their own Keyboard Viewer will be the quickest way to find out.

Comment: Here is the layout I get, when switching to Russian-PC: http://imgur.com/hKBvc0k. No "ё". Tom's layout worked.